Probability of Tyrion and Cersei Sitting Together at a Round Table
Problem. Tyrion, Cersei, and ten other people are sitting at a round table, with their seating arrangement randomly assigned. What is the probability that Tyrion and Cersei are sitting next to each other?
From Introduction to Probability by Joseph K. Blitzstein and Jessica Hwang.
Attempt. To solve this, I first fixed the seats numbered 1 through 12 and assigned each of the people to a seat. This gives us a sample space with size $ |S| = 12! $.
Tyrion can sit in any of the 12 seats. For each of Tyrion's positions, Cersei can sit in 2 possible arrangements (circular) to be seated next to him. The remaining 10 people can be seated in any of the remaining 10 seats.
So, the total number of favorable outcomes is $ 12 \cdot 2 \cdot 10! $.
Thus, the probability $ P(E) $ that Tyrion and Cersei are seated next to each other is:
$$
P(E) = \frac{12 \cdot 2 \cdot 10!}{12!} = \frac{2}{11}
$$
Question. The correct answer is supposed to be $ \frac{1}{6} $, as postulated here, or there, but I am not able to see logical flaws in my argumentation. My head is spinning. I'd really appreciate your help!

Your first link says $(2 × 10!)/(12!) =1/6$ but in fact $(2 × 10!)/(12!)=1/66$ which is clearly much too small.  It should have had something like $(2 × 10!)/(11!) =2/11$ or your $(12 × 2 × 10!)/(12!)=2/11$

There seems to be some AI powered stupidity behind the second link. An answer that claims that the solution is both 2/11 and  1/6.

Agree with @CarstenS - that second link is nonsense. It incorrectly states the actual probability depends on how you view the problem (obviously it cannot), proceeds to incorrectly apply one method, and then claims that the obviously different answers are actually the same anyway.

Your answer of $\frac2{11}$ is right, and $\frac16$ is wrong. Here's a short justification for $\frac2{11}$: by symmetry it doesn't matter where Tyrion sits. Wherever Tyrion sits, there are $11$ other seats which include $2$ next to him; so the probability of Cersei sitting next to him is $\frac2{11}$.
Note that this argument also shows that if there are $k$ seats with $k\ge3$, then the probability of Cersei sitting next to Tyrion is $\frac2{k-1}$. It would be instructive to go through the solutions that give $\frac16$ erroneously for $k=12$ and see what they give for smaller values of $k$—it might make it easier to find the mistakes in those solutions.

Here's a short justification I see what you did there.

Your reasoning and answer are correct. Let me address the incorrect arguments you link to.
From the first link:

In a seating arrangement with 12 people, there are 12! (factorial of
12) possible seating arrangements. The outcome is fully detailed about
the seating. 2 people can be seated in 2! Ways. There are 10 people
left to seat and there are 10! Ways to seat them. So, we get the
following:(2! × 10!)/(12!) = 1/6. Therefore, the probability that
Tyrion and Cersei are sitting next to each other is 1/6.

There are two problems with this. First, while there are $2!$ orders in which two people can sit, there are $12$ places to put them, so the actual numbers of ways to seat two people next to each other is $2! \cdot 12$, not $2!$. The second problem is that $\dfrac{2! \cdot 10!}{12!}$ is $1/66$, not $1/6$.
That link has a second argument, but it seems to be the same one worded differently, despite the claim to use a "smaller sample space".
As for the second link, it computes the probability as $\dfrac{2 \times 10!}{11!}$ and wrongly evaluates that expression as $1/6$, when in reality it simplifies to the correct answer, $2/11$.
